# New page not visible in Publish environment

Tags: aem

I create a new page under the 'services' menu in the Geometrixx site in CQ5. The navigation item is visible in the Publish environment (port 4503) but when clicked, the page is displayed as a blank page.

I have Activated the 'English' menu, the 'Services' menu and the new page too.  Am I missing something here ?

Comment: The most common reason for a blank page is if the code (i.e. `/apps/`) has not been deployed to publish. This is unlikely for Geometrixx, but worth checking that it's there.

Comment: Have you tried looking at "View Source"? If the page triggered an exception, you'll find a <div> there with a class that contains something like "page error", in which case you need to dig the exception out of the console (or in the crx-quickstart/logs directory of the filesystem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be a number of probable causes for this. Please check the below points:

1. The page's template/component is published as well.
2. Any new component developed and added to the page is published as well. (in `/apps/geometrixx`)
3. If the page requires login, you may first need to login to the Geometrixx site on publish environment

Please check if this helps.

Comment: I have faced the same problem. can you tell me how to publish the template or component

Comment: @SajithVijesekara  - if this is in your custom website, the template and comp. should be a part of your code. Please ensure the code is deployed properly. If you faced this in Geometrixx, then check steps #2 and #3 in my response. Also, why are you using Geometrixx now ? Its outdated and deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

can you try comparing the content node in crxde

```
http://localhost:4502/crxde
```

between author and publish mode for the newly created node

Comment: Yes, I compared them all and they are all same. Except the alphanumeric ID's (baseVersion, uuid etc.), which I guess., should be fine. Could there be any other reason ?